# When page is at the top image is not hiding javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that performs the following task: when the page is initially loaded it is hidden; otherwise it is shown. The code I have written makes perfect sense but it seems to work just once when the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        xyz = $('.verb_logo_w');

        if(document.body.scrollTop === 0){
            xyz.hide();
        };

        window.onscroll = function(e){
            xyz.show();
        };
    },10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the hide function to the scroll event too:

```
 $.scrollTop = function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('.verb_logo_w').hide();
    } else {
        $('.verb_logo_w').show();
    }
};
//onScroll
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $.scrollTop();
});
//Init
$.scrollTop();
```

And move this block outside of the timeout.

Here is a working **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02duz08x/)**.

Text will only appears, if `scrollTop` value is not 0 at page load, and on scroll.

Comment: Thanks mate, sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the "scroll" event properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $xyz = $('.verb_logo_w');
  
  function pageScrolled() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    
    // informative purpose
    console.log("scrollTop value: " + scrollTop);
    
    if( scrollTop === 0 ) {
      $xyz.show();
    } else {
      $xyz.hide();
    }
  }

  $(window).on("scroll", pageScrolled);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.verb_logo_w{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="verb_logo_w"><div>
```